# Fortify High: Access Specifier Manipulation issue in VAPT Java

Tags: java, fortify

- Access specifier manipulation issue occurs to the setAccessible(true).
- Recommendations: Access specifiers should only be changed by a privileged class using arguments that an attacker cannot set. All occurrences should be examined carefully.
- How can i avoid this issue , for the below line
    mListenerInfoField.setAccessible(true);
- This is the snippet of my code

  ```
  ListenerGetterIcs() {
      mListenerInfoField = getField(View.class, "mListenerInfo");
      if ( !Modifier.isPublic(mListenerInfoField.getModifiers())) {
          mListenerInfoField.setAccessible(true);
      }
      mOnClickListenerField = getField("android.view.View$ListenerInfo", "mOnClickListener");
  }
  ```

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details about your problem

Answer (score 0):

Although, I am late to this. If someone else is looking for an answer then use below:

```
org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(mListenerInfoField);
```

instead of

```
mListenerInfoField.setAccessible(true);
```

I tested it and it's working perfectly fine. No complaints from Fortify as well.